# template not show menu items in joomla 1.7

Tags: templates, joomla, web

I am new in joomla 1.7 I have installed tx_freemium template but this template not showing menu items while other templates like beez_20,fruitshop etc work perfectely.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this works

1. log in admin menu
2. go to extensions > modules
3. search your usermenu
4. to the right your parameters add 'tx-menu' to class suffix
5. set the position where you want the menu, as a reference which position you want look here: http://demo.themexpert.com/joomla16/2011/freemium/index.php/2011-04-17-17-18-46/module-variations
6. save changes

that should work